# Change background of a div of fixed height on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div like the following:

```css
.block {
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.block:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h3>Something</h3>
  <br>
  <h4>Some other heading</h4>
</div>
```

Looks like a simple one. But the problem is the hover effect works only on the content not on the entire div. Is it because of the height parameter defined explicitly?

Comment: Seems good to me. The hover effect is on the entire .block div

Comment: It's working great for me, testing on OSX chrome, safari, firefox. Can you give us some more details on what you're testing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me!
Try adding

```css
background-color: black!important;
```

If that works then there's a chance something else in your CSS is blocking it from changing.

Answer (score 2):

It works how it should, though if the content of your `block` will overflow the 200px, the div and any other child element, which inherit background color, will show the black background.

So for example your `h3`/`h4` will not get black background but inherit the white font color, and in is this case make them "invisible" against the white background of the body.

If you want the div to grow with its content, change it to `min-width: 200px;`, or else you might should set `overflow: auto`, so it scroll the content.

```css
.block {
  min-height: 200px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.block:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h3>Something</h3>
  <br>
  <h4>Some other heading</h4>
  <br>
  <h4>Some other heading</h4>
  <br>
  <h4>Some other heading</h4>
</div>
```